# Getting 404 while using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I tried to create really simple Spring MVC project, I can access my default index.jsp file, but whenever I try to go to an endpoint defined in my controller, I get 404.

Using Tomcat

My web.xml:

```
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

test-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example" />

</beans>
```

And controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

[Also project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRvwF.png)

Pls help,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have Misplaced the Double Quotes near 'views' and missed a  '/'

Try this:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```